# Remove verb abbreviation and punctuation from string edges with python

Tags: python, regex, nltk, text-processing

How to remove noises from word (or sequence of words) edges. By noises I mean: `'s`, `'re`, `.`, `?`, `,`, `;`, etc. In other words, **punctuation** and **abbreviations**. But it needs to be only from left and right edges, noises within word should remain.

examples:

```
Apple.            Apple
Donald Trump's    Trump
They're           They
I'm               I
¿Hablas espanol?  Hablas espanhol
$12               12
H4ck3r            H4ck3r
What's up         What's up
```

So basically remove apostrophes, verb abbreviations and punctuation but only for the string edges (right/left). It seems `strip` doesn't work with full matches and couldn't find `re` suitable method only for edges.

Comment: You need to *fully* define the problem.  What principle or class makes `$` a punctuation mark?  How would you handle the contraction of "I would have": `I'd've` ?

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
import re

strings = ['Apple.', "Trump's", "They're", "I'm", "¿Hablas", "$12", "H4ck3r"]

rx = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')
filtered = [m.group(0) for string in strings for m in [rx.search(string)] if m]
print(filtered)
```

Yielding

```
['Apple', 'Trump', 'They', 'I', 'Hablas', '12', 'H4ck3r']
```

Instead of eating something away from the left or right, it simply takes the first match of word characters (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).

---

To apply it "in the wild", you could split the sentence first, like so:

```
sentence = "Apple. Trump's They're I'm ¿Hablas $12 H4ck3r"

rx = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')
filtered = [m.group(0) for string in sentence.split() for m in [rx.search(string)] if m]
print(filtered)
```

This obviously yields the same list as above.

Comment: Wouldn't [`[r.findall(s)[0] for s in strings]` using just `\w+`](https://tio.run/##HYy7CsIwFED3fMUlCLdFKWpdHdzq7hYzRE1paF7cRKRfJ/hj0TidAwdOXPIUfF@KcTFQBtKMKTiCwFOMVne4AX6hp4uYeNVJL0i66hldxec9qJtV/7ra7SuGw33uiUsWyfjcCNLdaPxDWdsQXl/r3zO1YithDAQJjAcl21K@) do the same, just shorter?

Comment: @ctwheels: It might be shorter to write but with `re.findall()` you first look for all matches, then use the first while discarding the rest. `re.search()` doesn't look for all matches in the first place. I haven't timed it though, would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['Apple.', "Trump's", "They're", "I'm", "¿Hablas", "$12", "H4ck3r"])

s.str.extract(r'(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
0     Apple
1     Trump
2      They
3         I
4    Hablas
5        12
6    H4ck3r
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Where is the benefit of the `pandas` overload here?